# Unit of Work Design Pattern

Tags: linq-to-sql, design-patterns, unit-of-work

Does anyone have any good links about a practical example of Unit of Work pattern with LINQ to SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only resource that I know off is the code for [Suteki Shop](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/), an ASP.Net MVC application which uses LINQ To SQL.

One change they carried out recently was to implement the Unit of work pattern in all the controllers.